# Facebook become test account page does not exist

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this [Turorial](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/) to integrate my Android application with Facebook but first of all I cannot open the link for creating a Facebook test account. I also searched it in Google and every link I get doesn't work. Am I searching for something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create test accounts and tie them to your app in the App settings page:
`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID_HERE/roles`

There's also an API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

That tutorial is over a year old, it should broadly be applicable but there have been many changes to Facebook's API and App Management tools since then

Comment: Ok so where to start. first create the app and then the test account or vice versa. This tutorial states the se3cond. Is there any newer tutorial because it will be my first app integrated with facebook and i do not know from where to start.

Comment: Create your app from your own (real) account, and in the app settings for the newly created app you can create a test user which will let you test the API without needing to use your own user and risk accidentally spamming your friends